# Unistall packages Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, x11, apt-get

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 only for a couple weeks. Yesterday I was connected to my terminal (at work) using ssh from my home windows laptop and I was trying to install remotely some programs to show me the full graphic desktop with no luck.
Anyway, I now find myself full of no-longer-useful packages that I want to remove. This is a list obtained using the command:

```
$ ls -l --time=ctime --time-style=long-iso /usr/share/applications|sort -r -k6|grep "\.desktop"|sed s/'\.desktop.*'//g|awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'
```

> 2018-05-03 20:38 xscreensaver-properties
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-terminal
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-taskmanager
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-sensors
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-screenshooter
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-power-manager-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-notifyd-config
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-notes
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-dict
>   2018-05-03 20:38 xfce4-clipman
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-xfcalendar-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-workspaces-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-wmtweaks-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-wm-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-ui-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-settings-manager
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-session-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-mouse-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-keyboard-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-display-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce-backdrop-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-settings-editor
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-session-logout
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-run
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-mime-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-appfinder
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-accessibility-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfce4-about
>   2018-05-03 20:37 xfcalendar
>   2018-05-03 20:37 thunar-volman-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 thunar-settings
>   2018-05-03 20:37 Thunar-folder-handler
>   2018-05-03 20:37 Thunar
>   2018-05-03 20:37 Thunar-bulk-rename
>   2018-05-03 20:37 panel-preferences
>   2018-05-03 20:37 panel-desktop-handler
>   2018-05-03 20:37 globaltime
>   2018-05-03 20:37 exo-web-browser
>   2018-05-03 20:37 exo-terminal-emulator
>   2018-05-03 20:37 exo-preferred-applications
>   2018-05-03 20:37 exo-mail-reader
>   2018-05-03 20:37 exo-file-manager

I tried with something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove exo-file-manager
```

but all I get is:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package exo-file-manager

How can I remove all the packages in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully removed a chunk of files with:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfconf xfce4-utils xfwm4 xfce4-session xfdesktop4 exo-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-terminal  thunar
```

Then I used a simple:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove package_name_here
```

for the remaining single packages.